# trigger function on firebase deploy functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to trigger a function everytime i re-deploy some funciont to firebase?

I have an specific firabase functions which i define inside GCP (this way when i do "firebase deploy" it doesnt re-deploy, unnisntal or touch in any form my current function)

but sometimes i might update this function manually on GCP and i would like to trigger a inner function of its code everytime it happens... is it possible?

ex:

```
exports.decrementAction = (req, res) => {/*do stuff*/res.status(200).send("ok")};

function auxiliary(){
//to be called on re-deploy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way for you to trigger a function within a code that is being redeployed. Since this code is only being deployed at the moment, this wouldn't be possible to be done automatically.

The alternative would be to have this function separately from the "root" function in the moment of deploying and use triggers to run this other Cloud Function, when the first is redeployed. This way, it would be possible to run it based in the deployment of the other.

You can get more information on the triggers available for Cloud Functions here: [Calling Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling). With them, you should be able to configure the timing for the execution.

Besides that, it might be worth it to raise a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling) for Google's to verify the possibility of adding this in future releases.

Let me know if the information clarified!

Answer (score 0):

I think there exists a manner.

With Pub/Sub you can catch logs from Stackdriver ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring)). Those services allow you to store only the logs related to the deployment of a Cloud Function.

The store could be, for instance, Cloud Firestore. As you should know, there is available a [trigger for Cloud Firestore events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

Finally, every time an event log related to a function's deployment is generated, it will be stored and triggers a function attached to that event. In the function, you can parse or filter the logs.